# Firebase request strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire

I want to fetch all users from the same company as the logged in user.

With `getUsersFromCompany(this.userData.company)` I do only get the user itself and nobody else.
When changing manually to another Company-ID (which is not the same ID as this.userData.company) all users are loading: `getUsersFromCompany('anotherCompanyID)`

```
 getUsersFromCompany(company) {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('company', '==', company)) 
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'uid' }).pipe(take(1)) as Observable<UserData>
  }
```

It seems to block all users when the company ID is the same, but why/how?

My firebase security rules for testing are set to

```
 match /users/{userId} {
     allow read: if request.auth != null    
}
```

Persistance was on, is now off

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of a document (from the Firestore console) that the query is returning but shouldn't, or vice versa? It'd also help if you show the exact value for `company` that works, and the one that doesn't (e.g. by using hard-coded values rather than a variable whose value we can't see).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing around it stayed really confussing. But it seemed to have something to do with angularfire...

Solution for me: Switching from

```
getUsersFromCompany(company) {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('company', '==', company)) 
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'uid' }).pipe(take(1)) as Observable<UserData>
  }
```

to

```
 async getUsersfromCompany(company) {
    const db = getFirestore();
    var users: any = []
    try {

      const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("company", "==", company));

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        users.push(doc.data())
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    return users
  }
```